# Converting date to weeks in while using Padas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to convert a date column into columns, but I got into an error with the indexing of the weeks:

The error is date 2018-01-01 is showing as Week 1, 2018-12-24 as Week 52, 2018-12-31 as Week 1 as well! This way I am ending up with two entries with Week 1 ; while I want to take 2018-01-08 as my Week 1 and **ignore 2018-01-01 altogether**!

This makes 2018-12-24 as Week 51, 2018-12-31 as Week 52! How may I do so?

```
sym_2018 = pd.read_csv('/content/2018_symptoms_dataset.csv')
sym_2019 = pd.read_csv('/content/2019_weekly_symptoms_dataset.csv')

df3 = sym_2018.append(sym_2019) # Add both sets to make 2018-2019 set.

df3 = sym_2018.append(sym_2019) # Add both sets to make 2018-2019 set.

# Converting values of Data column in datetime

df3['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['date']) # tweets_df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(tweets_df['Time'])

# Getting week value

df3['Week'] = df3['Date'].dt.isocalendar().week # Convert date to week and add a column Week.
df3['Year'] = df3['Date'].dt.isocalendar().year # Convert date to year and add a column Year.
```

Image showing dataframe:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think ouput is correct:

```
df3['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['Date'])

df3['Week'] = df3['Date'].dt.isocalendar().week 
df3['Year'] = df3['Date'].dt.isocalendar().year

print (df3)
        Date  Week  Year
0 2018-01-01     1  2018 <- first week in 2018 start 2018-01-01
1 2018-01-07     1  2018 <- first week in 2018 end 2018-01-07
2 2018-01-08     2  2018 <- second week in 2018
3 2018-12-31     1  2019 <- first week in 2019 start 2018-12-31
4 2019-01-06     1  2019 <- first week in 2019 end 2019-01-06
5 2019-01-07     2  2019 <- second week in 2019
```

Comment: Okay, I got your point thanks!